# Hiding Xamarin Forms Shell SearchHandler

Tags: shell, xamarin, searchbar

I have implemented a Xamarin Forms SearchHandler in my Shell project. I want to be able to "hide" it (and unhide it). There is no IsVisible property on it - any ideas how to hide the SearchHandler control?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - the property is actually SearchBarVisibility.

In my case, I created a value converter to and bound SearchBarVisibility to a property in my ViewModel.

My ValueConverter looks like this:

```
public class SearchVisibleConvert : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        SearchBoxVisibility searchBoxVisibility = SearchBoxVisibility.Expanded;
        if (value != null)
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case "Hidden":
                    searchBoxVisibility = SearchBoxVisibility.Hidden;
                    break;
                case "Collapsible":
                    searchBoxVisibility = SearchBoxVisibility.Collapsible;
                    break;
                default:
                    searchBoxVisibility = SearchBoxVisibility.Expanded;
                    break;
            }

        }
        return searchBoxVisibility;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My xaml looks like this:

```
 <Shell.SearchHandler>
    <controls:RouteSearchHandler
        x:Name="RouteSearch"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        DisplayMemberName="Street1"
        SearchBoxVisibility="{Binding TopSearchVisibility, Converter={StaticResource visibleConvert}}"
        ShowsResults="True" />
</Shell.SearchHandler>
```